# Not able to attach file from Slave machine and email using emailext in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have a Master (Unix) and a slave Machine (Windows).
I have created a Multibranch pipeline Project on Master and Trigger request all of the Process takes place in Slave. I am trying to send the HTML reports which are being generated at the Slave machine but get Exception:

```
ERROR: Error: No workspace found!  
Sending email to: abhishek.gaur1@pb.com  
[Pipeline] }  
[Pipeline] // stage  
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline  
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I am using the below code in Jenkinsfile:

```
success {
    emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/overview-features.html',
    body: '${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}',
    mimeType: 'text/html',
    subject: 'Success Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}',
    to: 'abhishek.gaur1@pb.com'
    }
```

The file should be attached to the email and sent. Currently it shows ERROR:

> Error: No workspace found!

Comment: Can you make sure you are executin this snipped inside a `node() { [...] }` block? Outside a node block you have no workspace, so if you include files, it needs to be inside. Edit: Seems you are using the declarative pipeline syntax, can you add the whole structure of your script?

Comment: pipeline {
    agent none


 tools { 
        maven 'MAVEN_HOME' 
       }
       
    stages {
        stage ('Compile Stage') {
   agent { label 'Developer30' }
            steps {
                  bat 'mvn clean'
               
            }
        }        #Developer30 being the name of the slave node, Though it is picking the HTML file and populating result in the Master

Comment: Best to edit it in your original post next time. I will post some answer to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my tests it seems the `agent none` case has a problem in configurations where the workspace is not allocated on the master.

`agent none` allows to set agents *per stage*, but the `post()` block doesn't allow to set an agent, it will run on master without workspace on the case of `agent none` from what i gathered.

So the only solution for declarative pipeline in that case would be to run the whole build on agent with label *Developer30*, if your example is complete it should be no problem.

```
pipeline { 

    agent { 
        label 'Developer30' 
    }

    tools { 
        maven 'MAVEN_HOME' 
    } 

    stages { 
        stage ('Compile Stage') {              
            steps { 
                bat 'mvn clean' 
            } 
        } 
    }

    post { 
        success { 
            // emailext stuff
        }
    }
}
```